# Python GData lib causes too much redirects

Tags: python, gdata-api, google-data-api, gdata-python-client

I'm using python GData to work with Google Calendar. I'm making really simple requests (e.g. create event), using OAuth authorization. 
Usually this works OK, but sometimes I'm receiving lots of 302 redirects, that leads to "Maximum redirects count reached" exception. 
If I re-try same request, it's usually works correct. 
I can't figure out, why is this happening, looks like it's a random event. 
As a walkthrough I wrote a code which retries requests few times, if there is such error, but may be there is an explanation of this behavior or even solutions to evade it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Google support forum:

> This might happen due to some issues in the Calendar servers and is not an error on your part. The best way to "resolve" this issue is to retry again.